# Xcode can’t be installed on “Macintosh HD” because macOS version 10.13.6 or later is required

Tags: xcode, macos

I am struggling to build app with unity on xcode.
In the beginning, I could not build the app on my iPhone from xcode because I got this error

> This iPhone 8 (Model A1863, A1905, A1906, A1907) is running iOS
>   12.1.2 (16C101), which may not be supported by this version of Xcode.

I also tried to install the older version xcode but it did not work since it requires new version as mentioned above.

Then, I attempted to reinstall xcode now and got error

> Xcode can’t be installed on “Macintosh HD” because macOS version
>   10.13.6 or later is required.

I am using version 10.12.6 macOS Sierra and I think that there should be  available installation version 10.13.6 on my App Store but 10.13 doesn't show up in my app store updates section.
Therefore, I went to Apple official page to upgrade to 10.13 but it said that this update requires macOS version 10.13.
I cannot install even version version 10.13.

How can I update my OS and install xcode to solve this issue ?

Comment: Based upon the first statement you got from the OS, you should have updated Xcode, so I do not understand why you went ahead and installed an older version. What you should do is upgrade your OS version, since you state it is 10.12.6 and there is an upgrade to 10.13.6. After that, upgrade Xcode and you should be set.

Comment: I cannot find any upgrade to 10.13.6 on my PC, that is why I am confusing.

Comment: Try going to System Preferences -> App Store and select ”Download newly available updates in the background.” (Or maybe even a full shut down ad booting up again)

Comment: It is already selected as well.

Answer (score 11):

- find the Xcode version corresponding to your current OS version here https://developer.apple.com/support/xcode/
- download it using your Apple Developer account here https://developer.apple.com/download/

Comment: For anyone who wasn't able to find their compatible release: Go to https://developer.apple.com/download/all/ (it has all the releases). Find the compatible release there, click "view details" and you should see a download button show up. Click it to download.

Answer (score 3):

To Install the latest macOs version,

> click on apple icon
>  click on About this Mac,
>  then click on software update

It will show you latest macOs version available, then you can install latest version of XCode
[Install Latest Mac Os Youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wApWevqW1tY)

Answer (score 1):

I had same problem
You must upgrade to latest macOS version.

Comment: I am doing that but I cannot install latest macOS. Even I tried to install version 10.13 from Apple official page but it said "This update requires macOS version 10.13."

Comment: I tried to update from mac settings but it says "Your mac is up to date"

Answer (score 1):

You need to download macOS version 10.13.6. You can download it from [here](https://support.apple.com/downloads/macOS%2520high%2520sierra) You may need to have a [developers account](https://developer.apple.com/programs/) but you can get a free one by going to Apple developers. You may need to google that. Once you get 10.13.6 loaded you can then download Xcode 10.1

Comment: It's now saying that i need to upgrade to version 10.15.4, Is there any way to install old versions of an app on App Store?